# how to convert viewstate to session state?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created the view state. i want to use the view state in different pages.Is is possible to access the view state in different pages?

else can  move  the view state in session object in asp.net c#. how to do that?

Comment: You are using ViewState wrong if you want to do this. But provide more context and we can explain more on what you should do.

Comment: If you decide to do exactly what you are asking for - check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622000/getting-asp-net-to-store-viewstate-in-the-session-rather-than-bulking-up-the-htm. Note that it is very strange to store shared information in view state, so you probably should re-think your approach (as answers suggest).

Answer (score 4):

> i want to use the view state in different pages

**Answer:** Then There is no Need to Use `ViewState`.You Should Use `Session` as Per Your Question

**What is ViewState**

> View State is one of the most important and useful client side state
>   management mechanism. It can store the page value at the time of post
>   back (Sending and Receiving information from Server) of your page.
>   ASP.NET pages provide the ViewState property as a built-in structure
>   for automatically storing values between multiple requests for the
>   same page.

**What is Session**

> Session provides a facility to store information on server memory. It
>   can support any type of object to store along with our own custom
>   objects. For every client, session data is stored separately, which
>   means session data is stored on a per client basis

You can Easily Convert Session to ViewState

```
if(Session["Key"]!=null)

Viewstate["Key"] = Session["Key"];
```

or Vice Versa

```
if(Viewstate["Key"]!=null)

Session["Key"]=Viewstate["Key"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Viewstate is equal to hidden field value. This is available to current page only where viewstate is defined and used. If you want to read those data in other pages it won't be available.

You need to store those values to `session` ,wherever you have done `ViewState["key"]= "value"`. And you mean to access key in other pages. `Viewstate` is saved as encoded value in hidden field whereas `session` value is stored in server memory.

e.g. `Session["key"] = "value"`.

Answer (score 1):

Session is used for multiple pages
while viewstate can only be use to one page

**How to convert session to viewstate.**

```
Viewstate["ABC"] = Session["ABC"]
```

but for multiple pages you **need session.**