# Asp.Net Viewstate verification failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, viewstate

Here is the issue description: I have a web-farm [load balanced] servers, and I had an ASP.Net web-forms site running without any issue at all! and recently without any change I started getting this error:

```
Event code: 4009 
Event message: Viewstate verification failed. Reason: Viewstate was invalid. 
Event time: 3/5/2019 1:24:31 AM 
Event time (UTC): 3/5/2019 6:24:31 AM 
Event ID: 40c56ea2a8ad4c059357fc4673003bbf 
Event sequence: 359 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 50204
```

I searched/read most of the Stack-overflow's threads and worked on making sure that all is in place as recommended also by [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/829743/troubleshooting-the-view-state-is-invalid-error-with-asp-net)

What I tried so far, maybe this could help someone else with this issue:

- Checked the viewstate in both servers and they're identical and not set to be autogenerated.
- Tried storing the viewstate in the session using this code:

  ```
   protected override object LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
          {
              return Session["_ViewState"];
          }

      protected override void SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(object viewState)
      {
          Session["_ViewState"] = viewState;
      }
  ```
- I tried to set `maxPageStateFieldLength="128"` in the web.config file and this cause this error:

  ```
  Error Message: Invalid viewstate: Missing field: __VIEWSTATE2414.
  Stack Trace: 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.get_RequestViewStateString()
  ```
- Extending the Idle Time-out property in the App Pool linked to the site in the IIS to 24hrs instead of 20 minutes
- I read this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2007/06/11/a-case-of-invalid-viewstate/)
- I have [ANTI_CSRF](https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/developer-guide-csrf) in the Master Page and this was before havong the viewState issue - I double checked that it is not causing this issue at all.

The bottom line is that I'm still getting the viewState invalid exception, but hope this list could help the others.

Comment: Did you verify that MachineKey is really, really the same on all servers? Maybe a new machine was added recently?

Comment: If you mean checking it on the IIS panel, then yes i double checked and they're identical and also the web.cofig also matches the values set in the IIS -> Machine Key on both servers. @PeterB

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I worked around it by applying what's suggested in this question:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622000/getting-asp-net-to-store-viewstate-in-the-session-rather-than-bulking-up-the-htm/4627245)

it is very close to the one you applied when you stored the ViewState in the session but in a different approach - hope this helps.